# What is difference between filterable with result and Filterable with no result in magento Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, indexing

Basically why magento uses filterable with result and filterable with no result in magento attribute.
What is the benefit of that attribute if that is  Filterable with no result.
Basically, I created more attributes in magento and all are filterable with result.
Now I want to do some changes in my attributes Because its not indexing properly.
I created 300 attributes in magento.Now i need to change this because on flat product its, not indexing.

Comment: when we use the option, "filterable with results", then we will get only the attribute- options available for the product . Similarly when use the option, "filterable with no results" , then we will get all the attribute-options.

Comment: @ Ajitha Ms Can You briefly explain in answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use for **layered navigation**.   Filterable (with results) means that links will only appear for values where the number of results (the number in parentheses next to each value) is greater than zero. Filterable (no results) means that links will appear for all values, whether the number of results is zero or greater.