# Magento 1.X explanation on attributs

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1.6

I have to work with attributes and I'd like to understand how it really works.

So first of all, in the BackOffice can someone explain me :

[image: columns of attributes]
On this picture above what is the difference between :

- on the `scope` column : `Store View` , `Global` and `Website`. What does that change ?
- on the `system` and `comparable`column : What does that mean ? What is the impact if I put `system` to yes / no ? Same question for `comparable` column.
- on the column `Use in Layered Navigation` : What is the difference between `Filterable (with results)`, `Filterable (no results)` and `No`

Thx a lot in advance for your answers.
If you got any website that explains what are the difference between all of this I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Scope: when the attribute will be used. While it's not exactly the same, you can find info about scopes [here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html).

System: if an attribute was created by the system, it will show Yes. Most of the attributes you will create will show No if manually/programatically created but I've seen exceptions.

Comparable: is this attribute going to be used in the compare? Yes|No, you choose.

Use in Layered Navigation: attribute used for filtering. From [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65732/what-is-difference-between-filterable-with-result-and-filterable-with-no-result) I got

> Filterable (with results) means that links will only appear for values
>   where the number of results (the number in parentheses next to each
>   value) is greater than zero. Filterable (no results) means that links
>   will appear for all values, whether the number of results is zero or
>   greater.